# Getting permission denied when using a token generated in Hashicorp vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I am exploring Hashicorp Vault for secure storage. I have a root account setup and I have logged in to the UI and created the below given policy through the UI.
The name of the policy is `app-readonly`. I had the policy like below

```
  path "secret/clients-integration" {
        capabilities = ["read"]
    }
```

I have executed the below command to create a token as a root user

`vault token create -policy=app-readonly -display-name=readonly-app-token -orphan=true -no-default-policy`

This command has generated a token, when I use the token in postman to read the secrets stored, I am getting error like below,

```
{
    "errors": [
        "1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"
    ]
}
```

Upon this error, I felt that the KV is not accessible so modified the above policy to like below

```
path "secrets/kv/secret/clients-integration" {
    capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

However, now also, I am unable to read / view the tokens through the UI / postman. Actually the UI shows only the Ui shows only the `cubbyhole` and the `kv` itself is not visible, can you please help me with the right policy change to allow the token to read the secrets.

**EDIT**
Latest trials

```
path "secret/data/clients-integration" {
    capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

I am using the latest version of KV => version 2 and I am checking in both the UI and the API.
The API however has the below like url

`http://host:8080/v1/kv/data/secret/clients-integration?version=2`

The data can be obtained using the root token in the same api

Answer (score 1):

It took me a bit to understand how paths show up in Vault UI because it is hard to make sense of when permissions aren't set right.

Each engine is accessed at its mount point. List yours with `vault read sys/mounts`. The UI shows these at the root, such as cubbyhole.

If an engine mount is within a subpath, and the logged in user doesn't have permissions to the subpath parent, navigation can end up with access denied or not showing in the UI.

You can jump straight into the deeper path with the UI URL, or, enable permission to the parent, or, eliminate the parent.

More info [here](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000953148-Vault-UI-Secrets-Navigation).